# Captures the close button as QMessageBox.Ok

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I have an if statement in my QMessageBox that is supposed to check whether the user clicked on okay, but when the user closes the QMessageBox the statement is true for some reason (despite the user not clicking on Ok).

```
def update_msgbox(self):
        from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QDialogButtonBox
        self.msg = QMessageBox()
        self.grid_layout = self.msg.layout()

        self.qt_msgboxex_icon_label = self.msg.findChild(QLabel, "qt_msgboxex_icon_label")
        self.qt_msgboxex_icon_label.deleteLater()

        self.qt_msgbox_label = self.msg.findChild(QLabel, "qt_msgbox_label")
        self.qt_msgbox_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.grid_layout.removeWidget(self.qt_msgbox_label)

        self.qt_msgbox_buttonbox = self.msg.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, "qt_msgbox_buttonbox")
        self.grid_layout.removeWidget(self.qt_msgbox_buttonbox)

        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.qt_msgbox_label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.qt_msgbox_buttonbox, 1, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)


        self.msg.setWindowTitle("  Software Update")
        self.msg.setText("A software update is available.<br>Do you want to update now?<br>")
        self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.msg.setStyleSheet("QLabel{min-width: 200px;}")
        self.msg.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("CalculatorLogo(150p)_1.0.0.ico"))

        if self.msg.exec_() == QMessageBox.Ok:
                return True

        else: 
                return False
```

Comment: You only put a button there, so the result will always be that. As the [exec documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#exec) explains, the returned value is always a standard button. And, in any case, it's not really clear what you want: if you only put a button, why do you want to perform a different action when the user closes the window instead (which, from the UX perspective, is fundamentally the same thing)?

Comment: I would like to treat the X (the close button) as a second button if possible

Comment: @yem What is the point of hacking `QMessageBox` like that? It would be far simpler to just write your own dialog that works the way you want.

Comment: yeah. I guess I can try it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Note: doing different things depending on the fact that the user has cancelled the message box instead of clicking the *only* button is not a very good idea, and will certainly result in crating a lot of confusion to the user. Consider adding a Cancel button instead.

A possible solution could be to add a cancel button anyway, but then *hide* it.

```
self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok|QMessageBox.Cancel)
self.msg.button(QMessageBox.Cancel).setVisible(False)
```